# Vietnamese characters are garbled after export and import

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, navicat

I exported a table in Oracle (which has Vietnamese text) from computer A with::

```
exp system/***** BUFFER=64000 FILE=/tmp/export.dmp TABLES=(USERS.AREA) GRANTS=N INDEXES=NO ROWS=Y
```

Then I imported that dump file on computer B (Centos same as A)

```
imp system/***** file="/tmp/export_table.dmp"
```

But when I query in SQL*Plus I see question marks instead of Vietnamese characters:

```
SELECT AREA_ID,AREA_NAME,COMMENTS FROM USERS.AREA WHERE ROWNUM<2;
```

[image: image01]

I tried setting NLS_LANG="American_Amarica.VN8VN3" on computer A before I execute EXP and IMP command ,but the result was the same.

Then I connected to computer A using a Windows client, Navicat for Oracle. But to my surprise, in one database ,I imported two tables, one is garbled, the other is not.
[image: image2]

Questions:

1. Did I export *.dmp incorrectly?
2. Is the computer B environment wrong?
3. Is there an incorrect setting in my Windows Navicat client?
4. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Data pump has been around for 13 years, you should try it if you are in 10g or after: https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g

Comment: What is the character set of the source database?  What is the character set of the destination database?  What was the `NLS_LANG` of the operating system session where you did the export?  For the import?  What does `dump` show is stored in both the source and the target database?

Comment: It isn't clear if you had the same NLS_LANG settings when you imported the two tables (one 'garbled', one not); but if you did, does one have nvarchr2 columns while the other has varchar2? The national character sets might be relevant as well as the database character sts

Comment: on Computer A(Source Database):
 select userenv('language') from dual;
`AMERICAN_AMERICA.VN8VN3`