# VARCHAR2 field and NVARCHAR2 exsit in the same table,the former is correct,the latter was garbled

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

the database A field Type is:
select column_name,data_type From all_tab_columns ;

```
COLUMN_NAME             DATA_TYPE
------------------------------------
NAME                    VARCHAR2
ID_ISSUE_PLACE          VARCHAR2
NATIONALITY             NVARCHAR2
```

I want to export a table with expdp:

```
expdp abc/123 tables=A.CUST:PARTNUM_0 exclude=grant,index,contraint,statistics,trigger DIRECTORY=DATATMP filesize=100M dumpfile=expdp_%U.dmp parallel=4 cluster=N COMPRESSION=DATA_ONLY
```

Then,I import the dmp file to my local oracle,the field 'NATIONALITY' is correct , but the other field is garbled.

```
impdp abc/123 DIRECTORY=DATATMP DUMPFILE=expdp_01.dmp
```

> [oracle@db01 tmp]$ impdp bi71/bi71 DIRECTORY=datatmp
>   DUMPFILE=expdp_01.dmp
>
> Import: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Sep 6 11:18:05 2016
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights
>   reserved.
>
> Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release
>   11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options Master table
>   "A"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded Starting
>   "A"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01":  abc/******** DIRECTORY=datatmp
>   DUMPFILE=expdp_01.dmp  Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
>   Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA . . imported
>   "A"."CUST":"PARTNUM_0"      5.990 MB   78037 rows

**Statement:Not a windows client problems,because the vietnamese charecter has been displayed properly.Here with reason screenshot windows client, is to make the results better clarity.**

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi1wU.png)

**I found a rule,once vietnamese nationality in this line appears,the field NAME,ID_ISSUE_PLACE are garbled.**

How to resolve? thanks(^_^).

Comment: What is the source database character set?  What is the destination database character set?  What is the `nls_lang` on the client doing the export and import?  What does `dump(name)` show is physically stored for one of the strings that is garbled?

Comment: all of nls_lang are **AMERICAN_AMERICA.VN8VN3**

Comment: OK.  What is the source and target database character set?

Comment: What are the national character sets on the two databases too (since you're asking about a nvarchar2 column)?

Comment: Do you think you get a better answer when you ask the same question three times? http://stackoverflow.com/q/39162049/3027266  http://stackoverflow.com/q/39249204/3027266